# How to skip a <br> or any string while parsing json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jspdf-autotable

I have json array object as a result of jquery ajax call. 
I have used "< br >" tag in my python code to format my data in DOM. I want to skip this "< br >" tag as I am converting the ajax response json data into pdf file using jspdf and js auto table. 
Is there a simple way to skip a set of string ("< br >" in this case) while looping through the json array object.
Here is the one of the object in json array

```
{"content":{"rows":[["25.07. ","ma","","","","10:44 - 10:51 <br>","10:57","0:00"],["26.07. ","ti","","","","","","0:00"],["27.07. ","ke","","","","","","0:00"],["28.07. ","to","","","","","","0:00"],["29.07. ","pe","","","","","","0:00"],["30.07. ","la","","","","","","0:00"],["31.07. ","su","","","","","","0:00"],["01.08. ","ma","","","","","","0:00"],["02.08. ","ti","","","","","","0:00"],["03.08. ","ke","","","","","","0:00"],["04.08. ","to","","","","","","0:00"],["05.08. ","pe","","","","","","0:00"],["06.08. ","la","","","","","","0:00"],["07.08. ","su","","","","","","0:00"]],"data":[["25.07. ","ma","","","","10:44 - 10:51 <br>","10:57","0:00"],["26.07. ","ti","","","","","","0:00"],["27.07. ","ke","","","","","","0:00"],["28.07. ","to","","","","","","0:00"],["29.07. ","pe","","","","","","0:00"],["30.07. ","la","","","","","","0:00"],["31.07. ","su","","","","","","0:00"],["01.08. ","ma","","","","","","0:00"],["02.08. ","ti","","","","","","0:00"],["03.08. ","ke","","","","","","0:00"],["04.08. ","to","","","","","","0:00"],["05.08. ","pe","","","","","","0:00"],["06.08. ","la","","","","","","0:00"],["07.08. ","su","","","","","","0:00"]],"columns":["Pvm","Päivä","Sisään","Ulos työ","Ulos oma asia","Ulos muu","Ulos","Työaika"]},"title":"peter pan 25.07. - 07.08.2016 0:00"}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: The json file or the whole code ?

Comment: The json and the expected result

Comment: I have just updated the question. I hope it explains the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question. The easiest way is to convert the jSON object to string using javascript stringify method and then replace any string using javascript replace method. I will illustrate my answer as follows.

```
var jsonObject = someJsonArrayObject; // your json object
var jsonObjectStringify = JSON.stringify(jsonObject).replace(/<br>/g, ""); //convert to JSON string to remove the br tag
var newJsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonObjectStringify); //convert back to array
```

Simply put the string which you want to replace in between the two forward slashes along with g flag and replace it with whatever string you want. In my case I had to remove br tag so I replaced it with empty string. 
After that you have to convert the string back to json object in the last step.